# MySQL: Joining a table where multiple rows are part of the condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Trying so select some rows from a joined table where there are multiple relevant rows.
This is a very simplified version of the original query, so please no suggestions on the general table structure.

Table A

```
id, title
------------
1, housea
2, houseb
3, housec
4, housed
```

Table B

```
id, cid, attrib, val
--------------------
1, 1, bathrooms, 2
2, 1, bedrooms, 1
3, 2, bathrooms, 0
4, 1, pools, 1
5, 2, bedrooms, 1
6, 2, pools, 1
7, 3, bathrooms, 1
8, 4, bathrooms, 1
9, 4, bedrooms, 1
```

Select all objects which have at least one bathroom and one bedrooms.

So as result only these two should appear:

```
2, housea
4, housed
```

This is not working:

```
SELECT a.id, title
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b ON b.cid = a.id
WHERE (b.attrib = "bathrooms" AND b.val > 0) AND (b.attrib = "bedrooms" AND b.val > 0)
```

nor is this:

```
SELECT a.id, title
FROM tablea a
LEFT JOIN tableb b1 ON b1.cid = a.id AND (b1.attrib = "bathrooms" AND b1.val > 0) 
LEFT JOIN tableb b2 ON b2.cid = a.id AND (b2.attrib = "bedrooms" AND b2.val > 0)
```

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or INNER ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version is basically correct, except you want inner joins:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title
FROM tablea a JOIN
     tableb b1
     ON b1.cid = a.id AND (b1.attrib = 'bathrooms' AND b1.val > 0) JOIN
     tableb b2
     ON b2.cid = a.id AND (b2.attrib = 'bedrooms' AND b2.val > 0) ;
```

All your filtering is in the `ON` clauses, so no rows are actually being filtered out.  You would see the filtering if you looked at columns from `b1` or `b2`.

Comment: Don't understand your comment on the filtering. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Try running Correlated subquery as given below:

```
select a.id, a.title from tablea a where 2 >= 
(select count(b.cid) from tableb b where b.cid = a.id and b.attrib in ('bathrooms' , 'bedrooms') and b.val > 0 group by b.cid)
```